# Execute permission NTFS data partition

Tags: shell-script, permissions, partition

I'm trying to execute some scripts, which are located on my data partition, from the shell, but I have a problem with permissions.

```
bash: /media/storage/ss/script.py: Permission denied
```

Before running I provided the script execute permission with:

```
chmod +x script.py
```

Likely the problem is related to settings in my fstab-file. I have tried to edit my /etc/fstab settings.   Currently they are:

```
UUID=F6C09DB5C09D7C95 /media/storage/    ntfs-3g uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022,auto,rw 0 0
```

However I cannot see these updated uid and gid when I run:

Edit:

```
~$ stat /media/storage
```

Output:

```
  File: /media/storage/
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 804h/2052d  Inode: 5           Links: 1
Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
```

So how do I change my /etc/fstab file to have execute permission on my scripts on my ntfs data partition?

-- Edit --

```
~$ stat /media/storage/ss/script.py
```

Output:

```
  File: /media/storage/ss/script.py
  Size: 525         Blocks: 2          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 804h/2052d  Inode: 10208       Links: 1
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2019-03-13 13:17:31.980325600 +0000
Modify: 2019-03-13 13:14:11.690160100 +0000
Change: 2019-03-13 13:14:11.690160100 +0000
 Birth: -
```

And when I run:

```
~$ head -n 1 /media/storage/ss/script.py
```

Output:

```
 #! /usr/bin/env python
```

And when I run:

```
mount | grep /media/storage
```

Output:

```
/dev/sda4 on /media/storage type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096,user)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Err, `stat /media` isn't really interesting if your  `fstab` entry is for `/media/storage`. That being said, `stat /media/storage/ss/script.py` and `head -n 1  /media/storage/ss/script.py` could provide some additional information.

Comment: Ahh, true. Thank you for the suggestion. I have edited my stat command.

Comment: Thanks! Could you also add `mount | grep /media/storage` to show the actual set of options? Note that you don't need do add `edit` to your question, though, there is a [revision log](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/507476/revisions).

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I have added the output above.

Answer (score 2):

You've mounted `/media/storage` as `noexec`. `noexec` does not allow executing any binaries on the mounted file system (see `man 8 mount`).

You have to specify `exec` as mount option in your `fstab`. Note that your `fstab` entry is also missing the `defaults` option (see also `man 5 fstab`). You probably want something akin to

```
UUID=F6C09DB5C09D7C95 /media/storage/    ntfs-3g defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022 0 0
```

Check `man 5 fstab` or `man 8 mount` for the meaning of `defaults`. At least on my system, it's the same as

```
rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,nouser,async
```

but that depends on the file system.

If you want to check this without changing your `fstab`, try

```
mount -o remount,exec /media/storage/
```

first to remount `/media/storage/` with executable permissions and check your script again.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Mentioning the remount was a really useful hint/suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that a reboot would mount the data partition according to the edited /etc/fstab settings. However, that does not seem to be the case.

After running:

```
sudo mount -a
```

the problem was solved. Now I'm able to execute scripts on my data partition from the shell.

The result of stat /media/storage is now:

```
  File: /media/storage
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 804h/2052d  Inode: 5           Links: 1
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/  floris)   Gid: ( 1000/  floris)
```

I'll try to figure out what would be my appropriate /etc/fstab configuration, but my execute problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to exclude executable permissions on directories? Try using separate values for file mask fmask=0111 (fmask only applies to files, not directories) and directory mask dmask=0777 (applies to directories)

Comment: *"As you are trying to exclude executable permissions on directories..."*? Where do you see that in either question or configuration?

Comment: @ Zeta Actually I was not sure so asked for confirmation and based on assumption provided the recommendation

Comment: That's what comments are for. If you gain another 29 reputation [comment everywhere](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). 29 reputation needs three well-received answers.